# Who were the US Representatives for East Bay in the 1990s?

Tags: united-states, congress

In the US House of Representatives elections in 1990, 1992, 1994, and 1996, who won and became the US Representative for East Bay (California)?
I would also like to know the correct congressional district for each of them.

Comment: What state is Easter Bay in?  And have you checked Wikipedia to see if they're listed?

Comment: @Bobson, sorry my mistake, it is East Bay in California, and I tried to look for it, but there was som much redistricting going on that I had hoped that someone more knowledgeable of the locality would be able to answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Normally, I'd recommend [The Green Papers](http://www.thegreenpapers.com) for this, but they only go back to 2000.  I'm not sure where to look for older data.

Comment: A similar site is the [US Election Atlas](http://uselectionatlas.org), but it doesn't do House-level reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 2003 to 2013, it looks like the East Bay was part of the [9th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_9th_congressional_district) and [13th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_13th_congressional_district) congressional districts.  According to the Wikipedia links, both covered part of Alameda county since 1993.

[image: Congressional District 9 1993-2003 from Wikipedia]

The [7th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_7th_congressional_district) covered Contra Costa county from 1975-1993.  It covered part of Contra Costa from 1993-2003.  The [10th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_10th_congressional_district) also covered parts of Contra Costa and Alameda from 1975-2003.

Prior to 1993, it was the 7th, [8th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_8th_congressional_district), 9th, and 10th.  Wikipedia doesn't have a map for that period though.

For those interested, I found this by looking up the East Bay in Wikipedia and finding what it marked as the current district (the 9th).  Then I looked at how the 9th had been redistricted over time, paying special attention to representatives who had been redistricted into or out of the 9th.  Note that this method also tells me that the [11th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_11th_congressional_district) and [15th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_15th_congressional_district) currently represent parts of the East Bay.  For obvious reasons, I can't claim that this is a comprehensive result.

Someone who knows California better than I do might be able to say that the 11th or 15th represented parts of Alameda or Contra Costa in the 1993-2003 period.  The [San Francisco Bay Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Bay_Area) map on Wikipedia suggests that the counties are wider than the 9th and 13th districts.

1990:  [George Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Miller_%28politician%29) (7th), [Ron Dellums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Dellums) (8th), [Pete Stark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Stark) (9th), and [Don Edwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Edwards) (10th)
1992:  George Miller, Ron Dellums (9th), [Bill Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_P._Baker) (10th), and Pete Stark (13th)
1994:  George Miller, Ron Dellums, Bill Baker, and Pete Stark
1996:  George Miller, Ron Dellums, [Ellen Tauscher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_Tauscher) (10th), and Pete Stark

As I said, this may not be comprehensive.  Also, this may include some who only represented a small slice of what you might consider the East Bay.  All I can really say is that everyone listed covered part of Alameda or Contra Costa counties in the years given.

Comment: Nice sleuthing, Brythan.